# React.js make a phone call with a tag is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, tel, atag

```
   <NavLink exact to="/" className="nav-logo">
        <div className="nav-linker">
          <FaPhoneAlt size="19" className="nav-linker " />
          <a href="tel://+6199942413">call us!</a>
        </div>
        <div className="nav-linker">
          <FaMapMarkerAlt size="19" className="nav-linker " />
          <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/rc55DywgCJo26W28A">
            60 Bellevue Ave Gaythorne QLD 4115
          </a>
        </div>
```

i've simply tried a tag
it is supposed to make a phone call when it's pressed
does anyone know why it is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

`<a href="tel:+6199942413">call us!</a>` should work. Don't need the `//`.

Can also put `<FaPhoneAlt size="19" className="nav-linker " />`  inside the  `<a>` to make:

```
<a href="tel:+6199942413">
 <FaPhoneAlt size="19" className="nav-linker"/>
</a>
```

if you ever want to remove the text.